# Why won't my page expand to the increasing size of an absolutely positioned div?

Tags: html, css

I have a form fixed to the bottom of the page, and an absolutely positioned div above it. 
Output from the form correctly displays just above the form itself, but when the output fills the page, I cannot scroll up and view it. It seems that the output overflows the `body` element, and is ignored.

I've tried making the output div, called `main`, positioned relative, but the content does not appear where I want it.

My markup in Haml:

```
%body
.title-wrapper
  %h1
.main
.form-wrapper
  %form{:action => "/", :method => "post", :id => 'target'}
    %input{:type => "text", :name => "code", :class => "input"}
```

my CSS:

```
* {
  font-family: Menlo, sans-serif;
}

.main {
  font-size: 14pt;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3em;
  width: 70%;
}

.title-wrapper {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}

h1 {
  display: inherit;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
}

.form-wrapper {
  width: 97%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
```

Image:

[image: my page]

Comment: `positon: absolute` removes the element from the flow of the document. There for it's height/width will not register amongst other elements

Comment: @jmore009 : Is there a way to force the body element (which contains the 'main' div) to be aware of the size of its child element? I have tried for a long time and can't get the positioning of the output correct by setting the position to be relative or fixed.

Comment: Dont use positioning to do this. Use a combination of floats, margins, padding, inline-block, etc. I dont know what you're trying to do but in almost all cases you dont need to use them.

Comment: @jmore009 I'll do my best. thanks!

Comment: I guess you could've added an `overflow-y: auto;` and fixed height to the `.main` ? (even if it's generally a bad idea to go for absolute positionning)